# bower init error when creating bower.json

Tags: bower

I'm tryin to create a bower.json file.

I'd normally run `bower init` which would create the .json file.

Now I'm getting this error when I run `bower init`

```
    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:54
                    throw err;
                    ^

    Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/jason.dee/.config/configstore/bower-github.json'
    You don't have access to this file.

        at Error (native)
        at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:634:18)
        at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:502:33)
        at Object.create.all.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:35:26)
        at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:28:44)
        at readCachedConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/config.js:19:23)
        at defaultConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/config.js:11:12)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/index.js:16:32)
        at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    MacBook-Pro:Ang-js-starter jason.dee$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo chown -R <user>:<user> /home/<user>/.config/configstore
```

example => `sudo chown -R prappo:prappo /home/prappo/.config/configstore`

then,

```
bower init

bower install <package>
```

Comment: so I would use `sudo chown -R /Users/jason.dee/.config/configstore`